# Unable to increment javascript variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I am generating forms, and giving each generated form a prefix in the name field. I have done increments several times before, but something is causing the variable not to increment. This is essentially the code.

```
// Start at 2 because form 1 is in document already
var food_number = 2;
var food_form = '<input name="food_name_' + food_number + '"/>';

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_food_form').click( function(){
        $('#food-forms-cnt').append(food_form);
        food_number = food_number + 1;
    });
});
```

I have tried the following variations on the increment line.

```
food_number = food_number + 1;
food_number++;
++food_number;
```

As well as creating a separate variable i and using that to increment the variable food_number. The result for every form I create is this.

```
<input name="food_name_2"/>
```

I'm guessing that when the function is finished, the variable is not retaining new value. Is that correct? If so, how can I have the variable keep it's value. If that's not correct, what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your `food_form` is always having the name as `food_name_2` as you're not updating it. You're just updating the `food_number`.

You might think that `food_form` will automatically update since it has the reference of `food_number`, but that's not the case as food_form is now, just a `String`, with no information about `food_number`'s reference.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_food_form').click(function(){
        $('#food-forms-cnt').append($('<input />', {
            name: "food_name_" + (food_number++)
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: I am actually having to append a very large amount of html and would like to avoid having it inside the append statement. Also, isn't your appended statement mistyped? Is there something uncommon your doing inside the append?

Comment: @Goose ah yes. There was a typo. But you can just use this form. You can append jQuery objects directly.

Comment: I don't understand why your append doesn't say <input name="food_name_' + food_number++ + '"/>, why does it have the common after the input tag, followed by the bracket, with name without the equal sign, it's very strange in general

Answer (score 0):

You *are* successfully incrementing `food_number` in the handler, the problem is that you've already concatenated it into the `food_form` HTML string. To fix it, you have to regenerate the string in the handler:

```
// Start at 2 because form 1 is in document already
var food_number = 2;
var food_form_tem = '<input name="food_name_${food_number}"/>';

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_food_form').click( function(){
        food_form = food_form_tem.replace('${food_number}',food_number);
        $('#food-forms-cnt').append(food_form);
        ++food_number;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d1vf4amq/

Comment: I'm getting this in my html document. <input name="food_name_${food_number}"/>